# Using Array.prototype.forEach() Method

Tags: javascript

It is said that forEach() method is used to loop over any array like object .But here

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call({1:"a",2:"b"},function(eleVal,ele){alert(eleVal+":"+ele)})
```

The above code dont work ,why??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `{1: "a", 2: "b"}` is not an array, it's an object. `Array.forEach` requires that its target has a `length` property, which this object does not.

Try with an array such as `["a", "b"]` and it will work, or alternatively with the array look-alike

```
{0: "a", 1: "b", length: 2}
```

Comment: but it is array like object

Comment: It's more akin to a hash. It's not an array.

Comment: @Maizere: The ECMAScript [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18) details exactly how `.forEach` should work. Note that it requires the object to have a `length` property.

Comment: Since there is more than one person downvoting this answer, something must be wrong with it. Can we have some feedback please?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `.length` property to the object and it'll work.

Please note that you'll index will start at 0, so the first element will be undefined.

```
[].slice.call({1: 'a', 2: 'b', length: 3})
[undefined × 1, "a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it. I prefer this one since it doesn't modify the original object.

```
var obj = {1:"a", 2:"b"};
for(var i in obj) { if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i + ':' + obj[i]); }
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by saying why you have demonstrated this form of looping, when the OP has specified the `forEach` method. And consider filtering using `hasOwnProperty` within your loop. Your side effects will be different from the original.

Comment: @Maizere you said that your code didn't work, I only showed other way to solve the problem. Many people ask why their code doesn't work, when they only don't know a better way to do it. I had the best of intentions.

Comment: @Seza edit ur question so that i can upvote it ,thank u for ur exercise